# SQLite - Delete everything from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

The statement:

`DELETE from users;`

will delete everything from the table users. But how do I delete everything from three tables users, inactiveUsers, activeUsers

I tried this query in Firefox SQLite manager :

`DELETE from users, inactiveUsers, activeUsers;`

and it gives the error message -

SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: DELETE from users, inactiveUsers, activeUsers; [ near ",": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

Comment: I don't think you can execute DML on multiple tables in one statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't you run three queries?

```
DELETE from users;
DELETE from inactiveUsers;
DELETE from activeUsers;
```

If it is a huge problem for you, then you need to consider creating foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

Use 3 queries - one for each table.